# Contador de caracteres voltando ao valor padrão

Tags: javascript, html

Galera,

Estou com o seguinte problema,

Montei essa expressão em JAVASCRIPT, ela capta a quantidade de caracteres que digitei e subtrai com o MAXLENGTH, ela funciona porém estou usando JSON (para não dar post na página), quando clico no botão Incluir os caracteres que digitei ele continua do número que parei de digitar, por exemplo, digitei ALEXANDRE, fica 3991 caracteres, ao clicar em Incluir, ele deve retornar ao 4000, mas ele só retorna quando começo a digitar, quero que no evento do botão ele já volte para 4000, segue o código...

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).on("input", "#DescricaoCadastro", function () {
    var limite = 4000;
    var caracteresDigitados = $(this).val().length;
    var caracteresRestantes = limite - caracteresDigitados;
    $(".caracteres").text(caracteresRestantes + " Caracteres");

});
```

HTML:

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-11 stf-alignright caracteres"><span>4000 Caracteres</span></label>
```

Comment: Poderia mostrar o código que usa ao apertar o Incluir?

Comment: Alexandre, explica melhor a pergunta juntando mais detalhes e o código desse auscultador de eventos.

Comment: Segue o código do botão:

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCasoSucesso">Incluir caso de sucesso</button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

coloca um "onclick" no botão para quando ele for clicado, o contador altera pra 4000.

ex:

```
onclick="javascript: $('.caracteres').empty().append('<span>4000 Caracteres</span>')"
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!